# Android drawable memory management

Tags: android, image, memory-management, garbage-collection, android-glide

I implemented a RecyclerView in one of my Activities.
I use a customized RecyclerView adapter to load data from a SQLite Database (using Room and LiveData-structure) and display it in the view.

All of the rows have a large ImageView where I want to show a Drawable (just a .png). To do that I first tried to use the approach written on the [official Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) but it did not work well for me.
Therefore I am trying to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) as a library recommended by Google.

I have 16 drawables in my project. They all have a scaling between 800x800 and 1920x1080 pixels.

In my adapter I load the data from my database and based on the drawable id, the image as well (so there is no image data stored in the database; I did this previously).

Unfortunately my App cannot handle that amount of image cache which leads to an [OutOfMemoryError exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError). That's why I used

```
 android:largeHeap = "true"
```

in my Android Manifest.

I know this is not a good solution and I also know that there has to be a way to use less memory for such a small amount of pictures.

In Glide I use

```
 GlideApp
          .load(R.drawable.my_drawable)
          .fitcenter()
          .into(myImageView);
```

But unfortunately the image does not get shrinked or smaller. I thought that Glide can scale the image based on the size of the ImageView, screen size and so on.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to use less memory without fixed scaling so that my pictures not become ugly?

**EDIT:**
I first stored my images in the basic "drawable" folder in my project structure (copy and paste).
My second approach was the [gimp-android-xdpi addon](https://github.com/ncornette/gimp-android-xdpi) which exports images or icons for any android density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc.). But this did not help either.

Comment: Which drawable folder did you store that images?

Comment: @AbuYousuf I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

call override(horizontalSize, verticalSize).

This will resize the image before displaying it in the ImageView.

Comment: But what if I want to do this for different screen sizes (ImageView sizes)? I thought this is what `fitcenter()` is supposed to do?

Comment: maybe u can override size before u put this bitmap in imageview,
and watching oom is still occur

Comment: calculate your ImageView width and height and the use `override(imageVIewWidth, imageViewHeight).` method

Comment: You can store in `nodpi` folder . That folder images are not scaled by system. I

Comment: Sounds like an idea. But what is the purpose of `fitcenter()` or `centerCrop()`? Don't these methods do exactly that, just automatically?